# How to remove shadow from gnome-panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

How can I remove this shadow:

[image: panel with shadow]

from gnome-panel?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what desktop effects you have enabled and what theme you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

run it and go window decoration settings. Set window shadow to 'none'.

Comment: This removes shadows from all windows, not just from the panel.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to keep shadows on windows but remove them from the panel,

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

you can use go to Window decoration

[image]

and set **Shadow windows** to `(any) & !(type=Dock)`.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to logout and back in for this to take effect? Restarting compiz with "compiz --replace &" wasn't enough.

Comment: Ok, dunno what I'm doing wrong but I have followed this guide and it absolutely does not remove the drop shadow on the panel.

Comment: It doesn't work on Unity.

Comment: Just wanted to say this answer worked perfectly for me in gnome-classic. Or, as I like to call it, "gnome-proper". Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible without third party apps? Compiz config want to disable Ubuntu Unity Plugin, looks not good.

Answer (score 1):

you have to disable desktop effect from System>Preferences>Appearances and in the 'visual effects' tab select 'None'

though there might be some other way like in compizconfig-settings-manager without disabling desktop effect but that I dont know.

Comment: This removes all desktop effects, not just the shadow on the panel. This means Expo, Cube, Blur, Fade etc. etc. will no longer be active.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This solution is for the Unity panel in Ubuntu 11.04+, while the question was asked for `gnome-panel`.

Replace `/usr/share/unity/3/panel-shadow.png` with an invisible image. In other words, edit that PNG file and make it 100% transparent and remove the black shade in the image. The panel shadow will then disappear after a logout/login.

You could also create a new PNG file with a width of 1 px (height could be anything, preferably 20px) in [gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gimp) [image: Install gimp]
, and remove the background white layer. The entire PNG will then be transparent, and then you could put this PNG in `/usr/share/unity/3/panel-shadow.png`.

Comment: Feel free to ask the same question but tag it unity instead and then post this answer, that way we have a Q+A for both.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the location of the file is actually `/usr/share/unity/icons/panel-shadow.png`

Answer (score 0):

Just type or copy paste this: "any & !(type=dock)" under 'Shadow Windows' option in CCSM Window Decoration.