# How to enable the shadow of the top Gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add shadow to my Gnome Menu Bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9318/how-do-i-add-shadow-to-my-gnome-menu-bar)

Some weeks ago I've disabled the shadow of my top panel. And now I want to re-enable the shadow.
I doesn't remember how I disable the shadow, but I already know I haven't done it with Compiz. So the solution with ccsm & window decoration won't help me. I'm really sure I've edited a text file and restarted the panel to drop the shadow.
I've also tried to reset the panel with `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel 
pkill gnome-panel` but this also doesn't work.

May anyone out there help me?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/9318/how-do-i-add-shadow-to-my-gnome-menu-bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable metacity compositing

ALT+F2 ---> gconf-editor
apps ---> Metacity ----> General ( Tick the compositing box )

hope it's can help, also try to install latest restricted package for you graphic card to reduce the issue

**EDIT:**

Make sure compiz is activated, then launch ccsm and go to Window Decoration (make sure it is activated too) and on Shadow windows type any (if you only want shadows on panel but not on windows, type type=Dock). If it is still not working, reset all the value in Window Decoration, just make sure Shadow windows = any. If it is still not working, go to Window Rules and make sure it is unactivated.

And if it still not working, make sure compiz is really activated and in ccsm go to Preferences and click on Reset to defaults, that will reset all the parameters of Compiz so if you have a lot of customs parameters you will lost all of them and will have to make them again but it will almost certainly solve the problem.

Comment: This doensn't work for me … Its already enabled …

Comment: ok, updated my answer try that