# How to disable the drop shadow effect at the edge of windows in Gnome Shell?

Tags: 13.04, gnome, window-decoration, ubuntu-gnome

Here is:

[image]

I try to find in **gnome-tweak-tool**, but I have no luck. I'm using Gnome Shell v3.8.3 on Ubuntu Gnome 13.04.

Comment: Not exactly what you were looking for, but try this: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/highly-configurable-elegance-colors.html It is a theme that you can customize, including drop shadows. Of course, you could look into a way to alter the default theme to remove the shadows, but I haven't touched a Gnome Theme in many years.

Comment: It seems to be impossible: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900681

Comment: If using [compiz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager/CompizFusion), you can use the `ccsm` settings manager to set window decorations such as this. There is more on it [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5669/how-to-remove-shadow-from-gnome-panel) - But this did not work very well for me Gnome 3.8.4 ...

Comment: @MaxwelLeite Did you try to find a specific style in system's CSS files?

Comment: @MaxwelLeite - could be that recovery-partition of your system with dual-boot with windows is "sweatening" somehow ?!

Comment: Is there a setting in the Themes that allows you to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

(Not tested)

Edit the theme manually by adding the following to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

> .window-frame {box-shadow: none;}

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/2achwa/tweaking_mutter_window_shadows/