# How to remove top panel shadow when maximized window touches it, in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I want to remove the shadow that appears in the top panel when a maximized window touches it. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I tried using compizconfig as suggested in this thread: [How to remove shadow from gnome-panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5669/how-to-remove-shadow-from-gnome-panel) and setting window shadows to 'none' or '(any) & !(type=Dock)', but it does not work.
How else can I remove this shadow?